# What does setting Apollo Server NODE_ENV to 'production' mode actually do (internally)?

Tags: node.js, graphql, apollo, production, apollo-server

We are using an Apollo Server as an 'interface' server in a large project -- that is it takes various APIs and converts them all to a single GraphQL API using 'schema stitching'.

Currently our start script is

```
"start": "tsc && NODE_ENV=development node dist/index.js"
```

and we changed it to

```
"start": "tsc && NODE_ENV=production node dist/index.js"
```

When we pushed to production we started getting errors in the 400 range (I don't have the exact error, as we reverted the push) when the client tried to access the interface server.

The only other change we made in our `/index.ts` file was in the configuration of the server itself

```
introspection: true,
        playground: !(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production')
```

In any case, as said, we reverted back to 'development', and all works fine.

What does setting `NODE_ENV` to `production` do internally?

I've looked through the Apollo Server docs but can't find anything.

I found this, under [Deploying With Heroku](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/deployment/heroku/) (we are not deploying with Heroku, but it's the only reference I could find)

> To enable the production mode of Apollo Server, you need to set the
> NODE_ENV variable to production.

But, again, what is the 'production mode' exactly? It could very well be I've missed the obvious documentation explaining this.

Comment: Are you by any chance using introspection? Because according to the documentation that is the other thing apart from the playground that is disabled in prod mode.

Answer (score 0):

Are you use `nodemon` plugin? And the nodemon config has already set ENV, such as: `"env": { "NODE_ENV": "development" }`.

other, try to using `cross-env` to set NODE_ENV.